# Wordpress Change ShortCodes' output html

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have a theme which i should translate I search for all files for specified texts and replace them with translations. But I'm stuck at shortcodes output. I can not find their output codes in theme scripts.

For example :

```
[trx_property_info]
```

Gives me this:

```
400 Sq Ft
```

But I wanna translate Sq Ft to m2

Comment: Are you sure this "trx_property_info" shortcode is add_shortcode() from the theme?

Comment: Idk really, I searched for all Sq strings in all files, changed them all but still same.

Comment: Did you find this shortcode in your theme?

Comment: It was on demo page, but i couldnt find the code that initialized.

Comment: Try to search in the plugins